# Are proper toric varieties necessarily projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $X$ be a proper complex algebraic variety with an open subset isomorphic to $T=(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$, and the $T$ action on itself extends to $X$.  Is $X$ necessarily projective?

Comment: Yes if $\dim X \le 2$, and not necessarily in general. See Oda, *Convex Bodies and Algebraic Geometry* (1985), Section 2.3, Corollary 2.16 and the surrounding discussion.

Comment: @MinseonShin Thanks for the clear reference!